# wxWidgets errors occur after upgrading gDEBugger

Tags: wxwidgets

all. Today I upgraded my gDEBugger (though I don't think it involves gDEBugger) to the latest version but problem occurs. When I tried to open gDEBugger, an alert window named "wxWidgets Debug Alert" pop-up, reporting that "....\src\common\xpmdecod.cpp(822):assert "i==colors_cnt" failed in wxXPMDecoder::ReadData(). Call stack: [00]wxConsole....balabala....", like follows.

[image]

All these words seem just like warnings and didn't affect the following work, however I am wondering why this problem occurs? What's the root cause? I am not familiar with wxWidgets and hopes those guru on it can help me resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a malformed XPM. As XPMs are typically embedded into the program itself, this is not supposed to happen, look at the XPMs used by `gdPerformanceCountersDialog::createAndLoadImageList()` to check this.

P.S. Next time you could just press `Ctrl+C` to copy the message box contents to clipboard as text instead of pasting in an image.